# Azure WebJobs 2.1 dependencies

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have updated Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs to 2.1.0.

It has installed a significant number of dependent NuGet packages.

What is the purpose and benefit of this design? Is this an attempt to make WebJobs more compatible between .Net Framework and .Net Core or there is a number of new features which require additional libraries? Actually it has increased size of the project, so having few WebJobs projects within solution increases server capacity requirements a lot as well as makes deployment time much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version really has some new features and the purpose of compatibility. You could find the difference between different versions of Azure WebJobs packages from this [article](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/2.1.0).

1.New feature

In article , we could find the version 2.1.0 has a ‘**Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions**’ package in dependencies, which the previous versions(such as 2.0.0) haven’t. If you want to use this dependency 
 to achieve some functions in code, you could install the new version.

2.Compatibility

You could notice the Azure.WebJobs 2.1.0 version  only supports the Azure.WebJobs.Core 2.1.0 version. It means the **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core** package can not be backward compatible. Their version needs to be consistent.

So which package version to install  depends on your personal requirement.  Besides, it seems that the package size is small,  I think it has slightly effect on performance.